# What is the meaning of “ ヒキョーだ”? What would be a good english word/phrase to replace it?

Tags: katakana

I am translating a manga and this is a word that I could not find a translation for. If someone could help it would be greatly appreciated!!

In the manga, there isnt really a sentence but the context is that one person just threatened the boy in order to get him to help them & The boy said “ヒキョーだ”

[the manga screenshot!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jYrd.jpg)

Comment: Additional context may be helpful, otherwise this might get closed as off-topic. Can you post the sentence this is from and your translation so far?

Comment: of course! i have added it, i hope its enough :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is 「卑怯{ひきょう}」 written in katakana.

「卑怯だ！」 means "You/He/They are/is a coward!", "That's unfair!", "That's so mean!", etc.

Without context, I could not tell you which one would fit best.

Comment: thank you so much!!!